# highlighting and animate the uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

i want to highlight or animate the uitableviewcell when local notification has been fired for that particular cell of the tableview. when i tap button in the local notification, it  opens the application, but does not highlight the cell for which the local notification has been fired. Plz Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight or select a row in table view use this -

```
[tblView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToBeHilighted inSection:sectionOfThatRow] animated:TRUE scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

and if you want a blink animation then call this method after 1 sec -

```
[tblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated];
```

Comment: deleteRowsAtIndexPaths will delete that row, i donot want to delete that row. just to get the blinkinh animation

Comment: thanx for your help again, i think so that i should be deselectrowatindexpath, but i want confirmation from your side